# Where should I setup AppBarConfiguration for DrawerLayout

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

In [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), it says:

```java
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
        new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();
```

but it does not say how `navController` is obtained. In the next paragraph, it says

> call `setupWithNavController()` from your main activity's onCreate() method, as shown below:
>
> ```java
>     NavHostFragment navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
>     NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
>     NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
>     NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
> ```

which indicates that the 2 snippets are in different files. So where should I place the first snippet (initializing `appBarConfiguration`)? Currently, I put them all in my main activity, and it *seems* to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to attach the appBarConfiguration to the NavigationUI with NavController using setupActionBarWithNavController() method. Code below shows an example,

```
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

setupWithNavController()  method is to attach NavigationView to NavigationUI

Comment: Could you explain why I should list the top-level, instead of just using `getGraph()`?

Comment: You can use either use top-level destinations or Navigation Graph from Navigation Controller. Either case, the documentation is explaining how to bind navigation view, navigation fragment host and app bar together.